# How to add an icon image as hint to EditBox in Android

Tags: android

I need to put the search image lens as hint in EditText. is it possible to do it in Android?

best regards,,

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I always have solved this by changing the drawable right.

You can do it on the layout xml file android:drawableRight="@drawable/search_icon" or programmatically using the [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) function.

Hope it helped! :)

Comment: Many Thanks.. it woks magically!! ... only one issue, it display the icon to right of edit box instead of left... so how to make displayed on left side?

Comment: just use the android:drawableLeft instead :) you can use left, right, top and bottom

Answer (score 3):

set background with search icon to editText and clear it on click event using `textWatcher` , `clickListener` or `touchListener` .

Answer (score 0):

I have just what you were asking for solution. It works great but keep in mind that Unicode support is buggy on Android.

1) Pick a character you like from unicode here 
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f50e/index.htm
then pick a font that supports it (and has visual representation of it that fits your design).

2) Download that font (keep an eye out for licensing and ttf file size)

3) Put the downloaded font in assets folder for example Symbola.ttf

4) Do this in your on create method

```
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Symbola.ttf");
    txtSearch.setHint("\uD83D\uDD0E");
    txtSearch.setTypeface(font);
//Unfortunatly you can't define "\uD83D\uDD0E" in strings xml, that is not supported.
```

5) If you don't like the characters in the font set txtSearch.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT); when user starts typing (Use text watcher onTextChanged(...))

Comment: EDIT: I just retested this and it appears to be much simpler now but I can't guarantee that it will work on every phone or OS version. You can just set txtSearch.setHint("\uD83D\uDD0E"); in onCreate and have a magnifying glass symbol