# How to add Image in Editbox with some text?

Tags: java, android, editbox

I am trying to add the image in Edit box with some text, but it is not showing the image. It is showing only texts.

Here is my xml.

```
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/favButton"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Add to "
     android:drawableRight="@drawable/white_star"
     android:layout_below="@id/priceText"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_black"
     android:padding="10dip"
     style="@style/ButtonText"
     android:onClick="onAddFavClick" />
```

Here is my Java Code.

```
 private void updateFavButton() {
    if (atmItem.isFav()) {

      favButton.setText("Remove from ");

    } else {

      favButton.setText("Add to ");

    }
 }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703283/how-can-i-add-an-image-on-edittext

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085040/how-to-add-an-icon-image-as-hint-to-editbox-in-android

Comment: you are saying edit text and u r using Button ??? In the xml what is this .u want rounded corner of the edit text or some thing else

Comment: yes sorry for that. I am using Button, but now It is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way also

```
<EditText

    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_image" />
```

Or for a reference you can [StackOverFlow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703283/how-can-i-add-an-image-on-edittext)

So for that you can use `android:drawableRight=""`

Comment: I did it but it was not giving me image, that's was my problem . Please see the question 1 more time.

Comment: @AmitJayaswal post the output image and the desired image

Answer (score 0):

The feature you want is known as `CompoundDrawable`.

There are attributes which you can set inside your `EditText`:

- [android:drawableLeft](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawableLeft)
- [android:drawableRight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawableRight)
- [android:drawableTop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawableTop)
- [android:drawableBottom](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawableBottom)

In your case, as you want to display image on right hand side, use `android:drawableRight`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple way if you want to go forward with XML

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/searchcards_back_relative" >

<ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/leftbutton"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:background="@drawable/searchleft"/>    

<LinearLayout android:focusable="true"
    android:id="@+id/searchcards_edit_search_lin"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/leftbutton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0px"
    android:background="@drawable/searchmiddle">

    <EditText 
        android:hint="Search Cards" 
        android:id="@+id/searchcards_edit_search"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:background="#0fff"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
<ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/rightbutton"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:background="@drawable/searchright"/> 

    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/searchcards_back_hitsearch"
        android:layout_width="35dp" 
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textSize="25px"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  
        android:background="#0222"    
        android:text=""/>

</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/searchcards_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edittext"
    android:divider="#fff"
    android:dividerHeight="1px"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4px"
    android:scrollbars="none"   />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

you should use .png images in drawable folder for left, middle and right images.
you can also take relative layout for doing this ... for more  keep googling...

Comment: Yes I am using png image.

Comment: Have you got your Answer ?

Comment: Yes I got the answer and I posted it also @Banku ...:-)

Answer (score 0):

I got the image simply with the following method

```
    favButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( 0, 0,R.drawable.white_star, 0);
```

Comment: That's what I said about in my answer but you did it programmatically.